# Java generics with parameter - inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, subclass, subtype

I have the following code:

```
public class Inheritance {

    class A<T,U,V>{

    }

    class B<T,U,V> extends A<T,U,T>{        

    }
}
```

Could somebody explain me, how it actually works? Does the Class B extend only A class, which parameters are "T,U,T", or it extends the actual A"T,U,V" class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let put it into real example:

```
 public class Inheritance {
        public static class A<T,U,V>{
             T t;
             U u;
             V v;

             A(T t, U u, V v) {
                this.t = t;
                this.u = u;
                this.v = v;
            }

            T getT() {return t;}
            U getU() {return u;}
            V getV() {return v;}
        }

        public static class B<T,U,V> extends A<T,U,T>{
            public B(T t, U u, V v) {
                super(t, u ,t);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B<Boolean, Integer, String> b = new B<>(false, 1, "string");
           // 't' attribute is Boolean 
           // since type parameter T of class B is Boolean
           Boolean t = b.getT(); 
           // 'v' attribute is Boolean 
           // since type parameters T and V of class A must have the same type as 
           // type parameter T of class B 
           Boolean v = b.getV(); 
        }
    }
```

Basically class B extends class A (which has three generic params). By declaring `B<T,U,V> extends A<T,U,T>` you just bind the A's first and A's third generic param to the same type of B's first param

As shown in example in constructor of class B we have three distinct types - Boolean, Integer, String, but in constructor of class A we have only two distinct types Boolean, Integer because 1st and 3th constructor param of class A are both bound to Boolean type

More on generics and inheritence can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: Please can you explain what you intend to show with your example? It isn't apparent.

Comment: yes, I updated  my answer and comment out the example

Answer (score 4):

`A`'s `T` = `B`'s `T`
`A`'s `U` = `B`'s `U`
`A`'s `V` = `B`'s `T`

```
B<String, Integer, Void> b = null;
A<String, Integer, String> a = b;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does the Class B extend only A class, which parameters are "T,U,T"

Yes, exactly.

> or it extends the actual A"T,U,V" class?

It's a template, there are no actual generic parameters. It's a way to match your own parameter types with the parent's ones. If there is a `B<String, Integer, Long>` instance, there will be a parent object `A<String, Integer, String>` backing it.

Answer (score 2):

In this code, the templated type "*identifiers*" for each class are not linked to each other, let me modify the snippet to explain what I mean :

```
public class Inheritance {
    class A<T,U,V> { }

    class B<I,J,K> extends A<I,J,I>{ }
}
```

The code is the same as before. You can see that there is no "naming" correlation between I,J,K and T,U,V.

Here the types I and J are forwarded to A. From A's perspective, a substitution is made with : T=I, U=J, V=I.